# Checking current language in a function

Tags: multi-language, plugin-wpml

I am running WordPress with "WPML Multilingual CMS", so that it has multiple language versions.

In a function used with `add_action('template_redirect',<functionname>)`, I need to find out what the current language is.

What should I call?

Comment: Used *`multi-language`* because that's was already used and multilingual was not.

Comment: Hi, @MikeSchinkel, I retagged this as `<3.0>` seems a meaningless tag... Also, I guess our comments became noise, I suggest removing both ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have no experience with the plugin whatsoever, but from a quick scout of their site, it looks like:

```
ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE
```

will give you the current language. Worth a try, anyway!

Comment: Works great! Thanx.

Comment: Warning: it will not work on WP with another plugins.

Answer (score 6):

Try this one, it worked very fine with me.

```
$lang=get_bloginfo("language");
```